# Show amount of rows per certain ID

Tags: views

So I have a custom table in my drupal database, where each record holds a user id and a tid to indicate a vote.

> id | uid | tid
>
> 17 | 1094630077237307 | 33

I would like to build a view which would display each TID (preferably with taxonomy name instead of just id) together with how many times that particular tid was voted for.
So lets say tid 33 is "Amsterdam" and there are 10 records from different users with tid 33, ideally the view would display:

> Amsterdam: 10

Now, I made my custom table available in views and tried to get this result using aggregation but all I've been able to produce is a view which gives me the amount of tids in the table.

Comment: Assuming that your custom table was correctly made available to Views could you share your view settings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it made me check my settings again and realised I had to set the aggregation for the tid on group, and the user id to count. I roughly have what I wanted now.